# pivot_table is not giving expected results

Tags: python, pandas

df:

```
id flag  year  amt
1  'Y'  2016  100
1  'Y'  2017  200
1  'Y'  2018  100
2  NaN  2016  100
2  'Y'  2017  200
```

I am pivoting on `year` and `amt`.

**Expected output:**

```
id flag 2016   2017   2018
1  'Y'  100.0  200.0  100.0
2   NaN 100.0  NaN    NaN
2  'Y'  NaN  200.0  NaN
```

code:

```
t = df.pivot_table(index['id','flag'],columns='year',values='amt').reset_index()
```

**Actual Output** I am getting with the above code:

```
id flag 2016   2017   2018
1  'Y'  100.0  200.0  100.0
2  'Y'  NaN    200.0  NaN
```

I am not sure why pivot filters out the record where `flag` is `NaN` in `df`.  What should i do get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `set_index/unstack`:

```
In [51]: df.set_index(['id','flag','year'])['amt'].unstack('year').reset_index()
Out[51]: 
year  id flag   2016   2017   2018
0      1    Y  100.0  200.0  100.0
1      2  NaN  100.0    NaN    NaN
2      2    Y    NaN  200.0    NaN
```

[`set_index(['id', 'flag', 'year'])`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) moves the `id`, `flag` and `year` columns into a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html). [`unstack('year')`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) moves the `year`-level of the MultiIndex into the column index. Unlike `pivot_table`, the `NaN` values in the index levels are preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html
There doesn't seem to be an ideal solution. So you can do this:

```
t = df.fillna(0).pivot_table(index=['id','flag'],columns='year',values='amt').reset_index()
t['flag'].mask(t['flag'].eq(0),np.nan,inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
year  id flag   2016   2017   2018
0      1  'Y'  100.0  200.0  100.0
1      2  NaN  100.0    NaN    NaN
2      2  'Y'    NaN  200.0    NaN
```

change `NaN` by a value, then `pivot` and reset `NaN` using `mask`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But this is just a dummy df that i created. changing the NaN by value in actual dataset is bit risky. Is there any other better solution?